# Create a git submodule from a specific repo hash or tag

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project which depends on Twitter bootstrap 2.x, however, when I add bootstrap as a submodule using the following:

```bash
git submodule add https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git
```

This brings in the latest version of bootstrap.

I would like to create a submodule for a specific tag, but haven't found a way to do that. Is this possible?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Once your submodule is created:

```
cd /path/to/yoursubmodule
git checkout yourTag
cd ..
git add yoursubmodule
git commit -m "use submoduile at tag xx"
git push
```

You records that way the fact you want a submodule at a certain tag.

Comment: @onmyway133 A submodule is always referencing a specifc SHA1. You can configure the parent repo to make a submodule update after a branch HEAD, but even then, the submodule itself doesn't "track" anything: it just checkout the SHA1 the parent repo has. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309

Comment: how does submodule know about that "specific SHA1" ?

Comment: @onmyway133 the submodule itself does not know, the parent repo does, through a gitlink, a special entry in its index, which memorize that specific SHA1. See the links in http://stackoverflow.com/a/29327427/6309.