# How to isolate projects/folders with git that are part of a large project?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, project-management

Is it possible with git hosted on Bitbucket to have a directory inside a git repo to be a subrepo with own access rights?

I am currently working with subversion where this is the case and want to switch to GitHub.

How can I isolate small projects within a huge codebase in order to work with freelancers that only see and work on that particular code which lives in a directory of that project?

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is best to work with submodules: your main project will have "references" (called **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, [special entries in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17442045/6309)) to your other repos.

[image: entries]

Those repos will be declared in your main project as submodules, but can be used independently by other developers.

Using [`git submodule add`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), you can reference a repo located in any Git repo hosting service you want: a BitBucket main repo can reference repos managed by GitHub.
That means that you main project can be *private* on BitBucket, while the dependencies (the submodules) are *public* repos on GitHub.