# How can I organise my project's codebase that targets multiple library versions

Tags: java, git, github, maven-3

I'm writing a small library `L1` that depends on a third party library `L2`. `L2` has multiple versions that `L1` needs to be able to support. Each version of `L2` is bound to a given specific API and target JDK. I have no control over `L2`.

For instance :

- `L2-v1.x` -> I need to be able to provide `L1-v1.x`
- `L2-v2.x` -> I need to be able to provide `L1-v2.x`
- `L2-v3.x` -> I need to be able to provide `L1-v3.x`

What would be the best way to organise code in git (what should I put in master / what branches / should I have multiple projects / multiple modules) knowing that I have to build the project using Maven and I want the build to be as simple as possible ?

Thank you in advance.

Edit: all versions of L2 are in Maven Central, all versions of L1 will have to be in Central.

Answer (score 1):

If those library sources are not in a maven repo, then you can follow "[Using Git Submodules for Maven Artifacts Not in Central](http://alex.nederlof.com/blog/2013/07/08/using-git-submodules-for-maven-artifacts-not-in-central/)".
[Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) is great for linking a prevision version of a repo into another.

Here is a version adapted to your setup:

> 1. You setup your Maven project to have a parent pom and your own project `L1` as a Maven module of that project.
> 2. You import the project you want into your project. For example the L2 project [at the right tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18756678/6309).

```
git submodule add /url/to/L2.git
cd L2
git checkout <L2-vy.x>
cd ..
git add .
git commit -m "Add submodule L2 at  <L2-vy.x>"
git push
```

> The `git submodule` command will now have cloned L2 repository in a folder called L2.
>   Git will have added a `.gitmodule` file which looks like this:

submodule ["L2"]
        path = L2
        url = /url/to/L2.git

> You directory structure should look like this

```
yourParentProject
- pom.xml 
- .git
- .gitmodule
- L1
  \- pom.xml
- L2
  \- pom.xml
```

> 3. In you parent pom.xml you add the L2 folder as a module.

```
<modules>
  <module>L1</module>
  <module>L2</module>
</modules>
```

> And in your project L1, you add L2 as a dependency:

```
<groupId>com.github.user.L2</groupId>
<artifactId>L2</artifactId>
<version>L2-vy.x</version>
```

> 4. Now everything is set-up. If you call `mvm test` on the parent project you will see that it first builds L2 and then your project L1.
>
> Using it
>
> When other developers clone your project, they need to install the module as well using git command:

```
git submodule update --init
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited my question : indeed all code of L1 is meant to be in Central, L2 versions are already available as dependencies. How does is impact your approach ?

Comment: @kraal as the linked article say, if L2 is in maven, then you don't need the module approach: a simple dependency declaration is enough.

Comment: Then how do I deal with submodules using different source and target JDKs ? Compiling everything with the same JDK may lead to unexpected bugs. Some projects use modules, other use different branches, other different projects, some use Maven qualifiers, well it's not clear what the best practice really is. So far I've been using modules, but I'm not convinced that it's the best solution.

Comment: @kraal I agree, and I don't have enough experience on that point to give advice. I'll leave my answer for others for whom it might apply.